# Importing LabelBox JSON Output to TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm working on an object detection model using TensorFlow and the Keras package. My first iteration did not provide great results, so I am now using LabelBox to draw bounding boxes around my images. LabelBox outputs one JSON file with all the images and labels, in a format like below. I'm trying now to import the labeled data, but can't find a good solution to doing so. I researched that I may need to convert the JSON to a TFRecord, but have not been able to find a clean script to do so. I am relatively new to python and machine learning, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

LabelBox OutputJson:

{

```
  "ID":"ck6wf4t9ocmuu0948rgi87ubd",
  "DataRow ID":"ck6wd5n327ea50bofdgbe9tz0",
  "Labeled Data":"https://storage.labelbox.com/ck5x5ecl07i3f0932i797y27k%2Fa9bb10c6-14dd-cc02-1cf6-ccec2b4905e7-Apple_DVI_Adapter_TRAIN_Table_19.jpg?Expires=1585607947466&KeyName=labelbox-assets-key-1&Signature=6Nf7YIr3gjsIkOEZtH2rMy5PJPg",
  "Label":{
     "objects":[
        {
           "featureId":"ck6wf4s5s1ndg0z79nv3x96pf",
           "schemaId":"ck6wdqfe9xqpy0c16ysemtuda",
           "title":"DVI",
           "value":"dvi",
           "color":"#FF0000",
           "bbox":{
              "top":142,
              "left":575,
              "height":694,
              "width":234
           },       "instanceURI":"https://api.labelbox.com/masks/feature/ck6wf4s5s1ndg0z79nv3x96pf?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJjazV4NWVjbG9mcXd5MDc3NnEwem9leGpyIiwib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uSWQiOiJjazV4NWVjbDA3aTNmMDkzMmk3OTd5MjdrIiwiaWF0IjoxNTg0Mzk4MzQ3LCJleHAiOjE1ODY5OTAzNDd9.hvNXnIiVNKWfHc_CUONYyXMQWKeY7IqSpqE3z3qNZJQ"
        }
     ],
     "classifications":[

     ]
  },
  "Created By":"",
  "Project Name":"",
  "Created At":"",
  "Updated At":"",
  "Seconds to Label":12.423,
  "External ID":"",
  "Agreement":null,
  "Benchmark Agreement":null,
  "Benchmark ID":null,
  "Benchmark Reference ID":null,
  "Dataset Name":"",
  "Reviews":[

  ],
  "View Label":"https://editor.labelbox.com?project=ck68mszgktd0f0700beuachz5&label=ck6wf4t9ocmuu0948rgi87ubd"
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a similar solution. What worked well for me was utilizing Roboflow. I made a free account and was able to convert LabelBox JSON output to TFRecords for model training. https://roboflow.com/convert/labelbox-json-to-tensorflow-tfrecord